# How to ant datepicker suffix icon change location?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I want to change calendar icon location without flex-flow:row-reverse. Any other way to do this?[image]

Comment: try using position absolute

Comment: it works but the calendar icon is not fixed. As I moved the page, its location changed doesnt stable.

Answer (score 0):

```
const StyledRangePicker = styled(RangePicker)`
    padding-left: 34px;

 .ant-picker-suffix {
      position: absolute;
      left: 6px;
      content: url(/assets/img/date-picker-icon.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: auto;
      background-position: center;
    }
```

and add width, height then problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element you can see that its container has a "flex" display.
so inside of class `ant-picker-input` you have 2 children:
input and suffix icon
and then you can do whatever you want :)